# selenium python uc driver extension download

Tags: selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

hello i have a problem im trying to make undetected driver on selenium python but if i put uc.driver the extension doesn't download and work but if i put webdriver the extension work good
how i can fix please help me

```
    driver_path = ChromeDriverManager().install()
    
    extension_path = "C:/Users/username/Desktop/extension.crx"
    
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_extension(extension_path)
    options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")

    s = ChromeService(driver_path)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
    
    driver.get("https://www.example.com/")
    
    time.sleep(3)
```

this is the code  please help me to download the extension on the threads on uc driver

trying to download and setup extension of chrome on uc.driver

Comment: You should use `playwright` instead of selenium, as it is a much newer library and does NOT require a webdriver. Works with chrome, msedge, firefox, webkit, and chromium. It is best to avoid selenium, if possible. [Installation and Documentation](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/intro)